# Does the Breit-Wheeler process produce stable electrons and positrons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

Reading this excellent experimental [research](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.052302#fulltext) (2021) outlined described also [here](https://www.bnl.gov/newsroom/news.php?a=119023) of the first possible realization of the [Breit-Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process) photon to fermion process $γ γ^{\prime} \rightarrow e^{+} e^{-}$, it was not clear to me if these produced by this experiment electrons and positrons inside the pairs have been efficiently isolated therefore preventing them to annihilate back to γ-photons and if yes, are these isolated in the experiment electrons and positrons produced by this process stable particles?

Can this be a potential antimatter fabrication application in the future?

Comment: 1. The problem with antimatter isn't *producing* it, it's *storing* it! 2. What do you mean by the electrons/positrons being "stable"? They're electron/positrons, they're exactly as (un)stable as any other free electron/positron - there is no particle identity that could track which process produced any given elementary particle.

Answer (score 3):

All electrons and positrons are stable in isolation.

I haven’t looked at the linked paper yet, but the photon-photon cross-section is *tiny*, which is why its detection in 2021 would have been new and interesting. If your goal were to produce and isolate positrons, it’d be much cheaper to take any source of multi-MeV electrons, point the beam at a lead plate whose thickness is roughly one “radiation length,” and use a steering magnet to separate the shower-produced electrons and positrons on the downstream side.

Antimatter is much easier to produce than it is to trap and store, because production is generally a high-energy process while storage generally wants low-energy particles.  The first papers about antihydrogen spectroscopy at CERN give excellent descriptions of the (different) cooling mechanisms for the positrons and the antiprotons, and then describe the challenges associated with trapping neutral antimatter atoms.  Even residual gas in the vacuum system is a major loss mechanism (and of course even the best vacuum system must be continuously and actively maintained against outgassing, seepage through flanges and welds, and so on).

Comment: Converting photon energy to baryons this seems like a futuristic application for the Star Trek replicator? Or bidirectional for the ST Transporter. "Beam me up Scotty!!"  :)

Comment: Now I’m imagining a Star Trek replicator which happily produces a cup of “Earl Grey, hot,” but the annihilation of the requisite antimatter instantly vaporizes everything within a few hundred meters.

Comment: he hee! Not if you are quick enough to isolate all antimatter and safely store it.  Or maybe in the future we can learn to convert a single γ-photon to an electron or positron without pair production :)